# Prevent Pages from breaking web link at slash

Tags: high-sierra, pages

I want to put a web link, right-justified, in the header of a page. There is room for the entire link to easily fit, but Pages keeps breaking it at one of the slashes.

Pages does:

```
            site.com/subdirectory/
                         page.html
```

What I want is:

```
   site.com/subdirectory/page.html
```

How can I force the link to display on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by:

- Clicking on the link; pressing escape at the resulting window; then pressing the left arrow to move to the beginning of the link...
- In the Format pane, under Text, on the Layout tab, changing the Indent values to zero.

The Indent values were defaulting to `0.5 in` for 'First' and 'Left'. Changing the 'First' value was enough to move the text correctly.